# only change z-index of a div and not each of it's children

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, z-index

I have a div which is overlapped by another div with a higher z-index. Each div contains similarly layered images.

When I change the z-indexes of the parent divs so that now the other div is on top, I need all their layered children in both divs to remain in their same respective orders as before, but be layered as a group according to their parent's new position.

Right now, to accomplish this, I have to change a div's z-index from 5 to 1, and it's children from 6,7,8 to 2,3,4. AND change the other div's z-index from 1 to 5, and its children from 2,3,4 to 6,7,8....

How can I change only the div's z-index? It's children will never need to change order relative to the parent div. So it seems like I shouldn't need to set each one every time.

Maybe instead of divs, I should use iframes?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: @JayBlanchard I tried "change a div's z-index from 5 to 1, and it's children from 6,7,8 to 2,3,4. AND change the other div's z-index from 1 to 5, and its children from 2,3,4 to 6,7,8"

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using? The relevant markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Child elements inherit the z-index of their parent. You might need to rethink your element hierarchy or positioning to accomplish your goal with those constraints. Post your code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can have a look.

Reference: [Understanding CSS z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Understanding_CSS_z-index)